# Qt 5.6 msvc static compile

Tags: qt

Can you give me simple steps to do a static build for qt 5.6 msvc 2013? . i read about it but i can't make it do static compile. 
what i did:

1- put the qt 5.6 src in C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0

2- in qt command prompt cd C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0

3- configure -static

and it show:
Unable to detect the platform from environment. Use -platform command line
argument or set the QMAKESPEC environment variable and run configure again.
See the README file for a list of supported operating systems and compilers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its work here:

- install python v2.7
- start menue -> all programs -> visual studio 2013 -> visual studio tools
- open Developer Command Prompt for VS2013
- in command line:

  - set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2013
  - set QTDIR=C:\Qt\QT-EVE~1.0\qtbase
  - set PATH=C:\Qt\QT-EVE~1.0\qtbase\bin;%PATH%
  - set PYTHONPATH=%C:\Python27%;C:\Python27\Lib
  - cd C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0
  - configure -static -platform win32-msvc2013  -nomake examples -nomake tests
- c or o
- nmake